# Understanding ask --true 0 not digit 0

Tags: c++

At the moment I am reading a C++ instruction book and I'm not understanding the following:

---

The Author says to `\0` that this is the true 0 and not the digit 0.

So maybe anyone could clarify what the difference between a true 0 and the digit 0 is?

Comment: `\0` is `NUL` character. Its [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) is 0.

Comment: To get the difference try `int('0') - int('\0')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\0` is used as a string terminating character. not to be confused with the character `0`, whose ascii value is 48. SO, when iterating over a null terminated C style string, when you compare the character to 0, the `\0` will yield `true`, but not the `0`.

Comment: so \0 is a control sign like \n\r etc, true?

Comment: @FelixLahmer Read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character).

Comment: @weaselfox Thanks i got it now!

Answer (score 1):

This statement

> The Author says to \0 that this is the true 0 and not the digit 0.

looks ambiguously.

Moreover I think there is a typo. Instead of `\0` there should be `'\0'`

I think the author meant character literals. For example '0' is a character literal that denotes digit 0 and has internal representation that is a code that differs from 0. For example for ASCII codes '0' has internal representation 48 or 0x30 (in hex). For EBCDIC '0' has internal representation 0xF0.

Character literal '\0' has indeed internal representation as 0. '\0' is a so-called `octal escape character literal`. For example '\010' is octal representation of decimal number 8.

As type `char` belongs to arithmetic types then when '\0' is used in some arithmetic expressions it indeed has value 0 while '0' has value either 0x30 (for ASCII), or 0xF0 (for EBCDIC) or something else depending on a coding system of symbols in used platform.

Answer (score 0):

`\0` is a NULL character in C++, Which is mostly used in terminating strings etc.,

Where as `0` is a numeric number digit.

Clearly explanation from c-faq,

```
C programmers must understand that NULL and 0 are interchangeable in pointer 
contexts, and that an uncast 0 is perfectly acceptable. Any usage of NULL (as 
opposed to 0) should be considered a gentle reminder that a pointer is involved;
programmers should not depend on it (either for their own understanding or the
compiler's) for distinguishing pointer 0's from integer 0's.

It is only in pointer contexts that NULL and 0 are equivalent. NULL should not be 
used when another kind of 0 is required, even though it might work, because doing
so sends the wrong stylistic message. (Furthermore, ANSI allows the definition of
NULL to be ((void *)0), which will not work at all in non-pointer contexts.) In
particular, do not use NULL when the ASCII null character (NUL) is desired. 
Provide your own definition

#define NUL '\0'

if you must.
```

Comment: That's the FAQ about `NULL`, which is the predecessor of `nullptr` in C++ today. This is about `char(0)` versus `'0'`